# How to implement can_typecast(type, value) in python?

Tags: python

I need to write a function that has following signature:

`can_typecast(value, type)`

Both `type` and `value` are of type `string`. Function should return `True` if value can be casted to type and `False` otherwise.

For example:

`can_typecast('abc', 'float64')` should return `False`

`can_typecast('12', 'str')` should return `True`

Is there a way to achieve this without using if/else for each type?

Comment: `float64` is not a Python type.

Comment: Why would you pass the name of a type instead of the type itself (`can_typecast('abc', float64)`)?  Typically, you just try it, and catch any exceptions that might be raised.

Comment: @DeepSpace It's not a built-in or standard type in Python; that doesn't mean a library or the user couldn't define one.

Comment: @DeepSpace correct, I am using python pandas. Can there be a generic solution that can work regardless?

Comment: @chepner due to circumstances, I only have the name

Comment: `s/circumstances/bug/`

Comment: @chepner I agree, so here is the scenario. I have a pandas DF in memory. User can make a request like wherever there is a value 10 in column age, make it 11. All is fine but what if user enters aa? How do I ensure type and value are compatible. [I am new to python]

Comment: @HarisHasan That's an XY problem. In the future please ask about your actual problem and not the solution you deem to be the correct solution.

Comment: Really, you don't do *anything*. You just *try* to do it, and catch the exception and react appropriately. This is typically described as "It's easer to ask forgiveness than permission".

Comment: @chepner unfortunately data frame doesn't throw the error, rather it changes the type of the column. So if you replace 11 with 'aa' it won't throw error, it will make the column type str

Comment: @HarisHasan then you just try and convert what the user typed to the appropriate type and catch errors before updating your dataframe. And/or you can do regexp validations etc beforehand ("-1" can be converted to an `int` but is still not a valid age).

Comment: You may want to have a look at django's validators (used to validate/sanitize/convert user inputs).

Comment: Oh and yes: there's _no_ "typecasting" in Python. "typecasting" means "interpret the data as this memory address as if it was of this type", which is irrelevant in Python. You can create an object from another of another type (ie `s = "42"; i = int(s)`) but this does not "cast" anything, `s` is still a string an `i` is a totally distinct `int` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is using `exec`, so you need to be ***very*** careful with the values that you allow the user to input into `value` and `type`:

```
def can_typecast(value, type):
    try:
        exec("{}('{}')".format(type, value))
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True

print(can_typecast('12', 'int'))
# True
print(can_typecast('12', 'str'))
# True
print(can_typecast('a', 'int'))
# False
```

If you are allowed to pass the type as type and not as a string, you don't need to rely on `exec`, you just try the conversion:

```
def can_typecast(value, type):
    try:
        type(value)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True

print(can_typecast('12', int))
# True
print(can_typecast('12', str))
# True
print(can_typecast('a', int))
# False
```

Comment: You are using `exec` too broadly; it would be sufficient to just use `eval(type)` (with the same caveats), then apply the result to `value` to see if an exception is raised.